# MPMusicPlayerController and setNowPlayingItem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm using `MPMusicPlayerController`, specifically with `setNowPlayingItem` protocol and it's for `cydia`. But I have some issues and theos' warning when i make. It seems that some of the protocols and methods are not working and I receive some warning like this:

```
Tweak.xm:177: warning: ‘MPMusicPlayerController’ may not respond to ‘-skipToPreviousItem’
Tweak.xm:188: warning: ‘MPMusicPlayerController’ may not respond to ‘-pause’
Tweak.xm:193: warning: ‘MPMusicPlayerController’ may not respond to ‘-play’
Tweak.xm:201: warning: ‘MPMusicPlayerController’ may not respond to ‘-skipToNextItem’
Tweak.xm:317: warning: ‘MPMusicPlayerController’ may not respond to ‘-setNowPlayingItem:’
```

Have anyone some ideas? I enter the protocol already in prototype

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's because of cydia - it sounds like a compilation issue.

Have you definitely got

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
```

in your file?

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. Can you add some code to the question - the lines that cause the warnings and the line that creates for music player?

Comment: MPMusicPlayerController *mp = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
[mp setNowPlayingItem:anMPMediaItem];

Answer (score 0):

have you added the `MediaPlayer.framework` to your project?

1. select your project in the project navigator
2. select your target on the right side
3. select the "Build Phases" tab
4. open "Link Binary With Libraries"
5. add your framework

Comment: A missing framework would cause linker errors, not compiler warnings :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MPMusicPlayerController, specifically with setNowPlayingItem. This is a complete online verses asset with an immense assortment of melody verses, data, what's more,  MPMusicPlayerController *mp = [MPMusicPlayerController. [downloadmp3music](https://ebuzz.com.ng)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)