# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, swift

I am using XCode 8.3 and Swift 3.

I am getting the following error related to the AudioToolboxFramework and x86_64 architecture:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMusicPlayerController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libdtdev.a(AudioStream.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My project targets iOS 10.3 and in build settings the Architectures are listed as:
`Standard Architecture (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCH_STANDARD)`

The valid architectures are:
`arm64 armv7 armv7s`

For the settings `Build Active Architectures Only`, I have it set to `YES` for DEBUG and `NO` for RELEASE.

Can anyone tell me why I'm still getting an error relating to `x86_64`? Is it possibly from another Framework?

My Podfile contains:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.4'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'ReachabilitySwift'
```

Actually, I've just changed the `Build Active Architectures Only` for DEBUG to `NO` and got a lot of errors saying `No such module 'ReachabilitySwift'` so maybe its related to that library? I also get the same error if I remove the `AudioToolbox.framework` from `General -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.

Also, I ran:
`lipo -info ./MyProject/Library/libdtdev.a`

and got this:
`Architectures in the fat file: ./MyProject/Library/libdtdev.a are: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64`

So there is definitely something defining the x86_64 arch.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 - it means your SDK does not support in simulator, check once in device

Comment: Check on a device? Like run it on an iPhone? I get the errors when I do CMD+B to build. So it doesn't matter if I have a device attached. Or do you mean I need to modify my Simulator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution from this link:
[MPMusicPlayerController and setNowPlayingItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572960/mpmusicplayercontroller-and-setnowplayingitem)

The solution was to add the MediaPlayer.framework to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

Comment: That's strange. That should be done automatically when you are importing.

Comment: Ye it's weird, but I upgraded the app from Xcode 7.3/Swift2 to Xcode 8.3/Swift3 so something must have gotten lost in translation. I'm also an Android dev and I'm just taking over after the iOS guy left the company so I'm sure a better iOS dev might have seen some other way to fix it!

Comment: Look into project settings under "Language - Modules", specifically "link frameworks automatically" and "enable modules". You should also have `use_frameworks!` in your podfile for Xcode 8.

Comment: Yes, both those settings are already enabled, and my Podfile has `use frameworks!`. Thanks.

Comment: I encountered this again, but this time I had to add: AudioToolbox, MediaPlayer, and AVFoundation frameworks.